# How to determine which JSP pages are being rendered?

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

I'm working on a legacy application that is using simple JSPs that are nested using `<jsp:include>`.

No frameworks are being used - just JSP Servlets and filters.

Can anyone suggest a way to trace which JSP pages are being rendered?

Perhaps there's a log, or maybe a hook in the rendering engine (Jasper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Filter which listens on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsp` and the `INCLUDE` dispatcher only.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>includeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.stackoverflow.q2242429.IncludeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>includeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Get the parent page by [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) and the include page by [`HttpServletRequest#getAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) with key `javax.servlet.include.servlet_path`:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest httpreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String parentPage = httpreq.getServletPath();
    String includePage = (String) httpreq.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.servlet_path");
    // Log it here?

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```